# How to improve PuppeteerSharp code to set input value and click button

Tags: javascript, c#, puppeteer-sharp

I have to use PuppeteerSharp to login to one web site.
The web page uses JavaScript to generate dynamic class, so each time when I tried to login, I can see different class name.
So using Puppeteer Recorder is useless, I can't use its code to login.
But I checked its HTML structure, I found it is rather simple: there is one submit form with 3 input fields, the first one is input field for User_Name,
the second input field for Password, the third is button to submit the form.
So nowadays, I can use the following code to login with a lot of keyboard typings.  But my code was NOT a good one, as other keyboard actions will make it a mess.
But I can't find any good PuppeteerSharp code to do something like this:
Find all 3 input fields, then type the user name in the first one, type the password in the second one, and click on the third one.
Please advise!

```
_page = await _bookie_browser.NewPageAsync();
await _page.SetViewportAsync((new ViewPortOptions { Width = 1920, Height = 3938 }));
await _page.GoToAsync("https://www.webpage.com");
await _page.WaitForTimeoutAsync(2000);
await _page.FocusAsync("input");
await _page.Keyboard.TypeAsync("username");
await _page.WaitForTimeoutAsync(1000);
await _page.Keyboard.PressAsync("Tab");
await _page.WaitForTimeoutAsync(1000);
await _page.Keyboard.TypeAsync("password");
await _page.Keyboard.PressAsync("Tab");
await _page.WaitForTimeoutAsync(1000);
await _page.Keyboard.PressAsync("Enter");
await _page.WaitForTimeoutAsync(1000);
```

Comment: You could try finding those inputs using XPath expressions.

Comment: Hello: as I didn't have the experience, do you have any code sample or any article on this topic?

Comment: Hello: thanks for your advice, I figured it out. It did work for Xpath!